# How does Angular evaluates expressions?

Tags: angular

```
  <div *ngIf="((one===one)&& (two===two)) || (one===two)"></div>
```

How does Angular evaluates this fairly complex expression?

Surely it's not using `eval`, then how does it parse and evaluates it?

Could some one point me to the right direction ?

I'm looking at `ngIf`'s source code, but doesn't seem to find anything interesting.

It seems like by the time `ngIf` receives the value, it's been already evaluated by angular.

Comment: As this is a generic question I guess regarding all templating engines, I'm adding Angularjs and Angular's tag.

Answer (score 1):

When Angular components are compiled, TypeScript (and from that in a following step JavaScript) is generated for all bindings and all components, directives, and pipes that need to be applied in templates.
This JavaScript is then just executed by the browser.

This is one of the main differences to AngularJS, where HTML with Angular binding constructs is added to the HTML loaded by the browser, then Angular parses the DOM and applies its logic.

In Angular 2 and later, the HTML is only added to the DOM **after** components templates are compiled. If you check the HTML in the browsers devtools, Angular-specific bindings are missing (or replaced if they include some non-Angular DOM-semantic)

With the **static module**, this happens when the Angular application is compiled by the developer (before deployment).
With the **dynamic module** component compilation can also happen at runtime. 
But it's still the same. Templates are only added to the DOM **after** Angular generated JS code for them and replaced/removed Angular-specific binding-syntax..

Comment: Yes, you should just look at the generated javascript file for that code.

Answer (score 0):

First :

The `*ngIf` directive is basically a shortcut for "surround with `<ng-template [ngIf]>`"

```
 <div *ngIf="expr"></div>


 <ng-template [ngIf]="expr">
   <div></div>
 </ng-template>
```

So basically it boils down to the same evaluation as Input bindings. You can search for information here :

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/guide/template-syntax.md

Note that when Angular runs change detection, it will check if any of the variables have changed, and if it's the case reevaluate if the component is to be shown/instantiated or not.